# WikiData - Specific country with flag and emojiflag by item ID

Tags: wikidata

I need to query the WikiData to get for an specific country code (that I've, for the example is Q414 (ARG), the flag and the emoji flag respective. The emoji, by I know, is on zxx lang, but anyway any of my solutions worked. Any help will be preciated.

```
SELECT ?label ?nombre_corto ?imagen_de_la_bandera WHERE {
  wd:Q414 rdfs:label ?label.
  OPTIONAL { ?label wdt:P1813 ?nombre_corto. }
  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "es"))
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?nombre_corto), "zxx"))
  OPTIONAL { ?label wdt:P41 ?imagen_de_la_bandera. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that countries are entities with ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 codes, your query should be:

```
#defaultView:ImageGrid
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?code ?emoji ?flag {
  # VALUES ?country {wd:Q414}
  ?country wdt:P298 ?code . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240 }
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P1813 ?emoji. FILTER(lang(?emoji)= "zxx") }
  OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P41 ?flag. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es" . }
} ORDER BY ?code
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcode%20%3Femoji%20%3Fflag%20%7B%0A%20%20%23%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7Bwd%3AQ414%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP298%20%3Fcode%20.%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP1813%20%3Femoji.%20FILTER%28lang%28%3Femoji%29%3D%20%22zxx%22%29%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP41%20%3Fflag.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode) (257 results)

The main problem of the original query is probably a mistype: you use `?label` instead of `wd:Q414` in two places. By the way, values of `?label` are literals, which cannot be subjects of RDF triples.

The SPARQL 1.1 [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) keyword allows to not repeat oneself and to avoid such mistypes.

---

There are minor remaining problems, which manifest themselves as duplicated country codes.

1. The first problem is that not only emojies can be used as short names with no linguistic content, consider [`wd:Q159`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q159#P1813) as an example.
   In order to filter out that "РОФ", your query should address *qualifiers* on `P1813`-statements:

   ```
   SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?code ?emoji ?flag {
     # VALUES ?country {wd:Q414}
     ?country wdt:P298 ?code . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240 }
     OPTIONAL { ?country p:P1813 [ ps:P1813 ?emoji ; pq:P31 wd:Q28840786 ] }
     OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P41 ?flag. }
     SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "es" . }
   } ORDER BY ?code
   ```

   [Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcode%20%3Femoji%20%3Fflag%20%7B%0A%20%20%23%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7Bwd%3AQ414%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP298%20%3Fcode%20.%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP1813%20%5B%20ps%3AP1813%20%3Femoji%20%3B%20pq%3AP31%20wd%3AQ28840786%20%5D%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP41%20%3Fflag.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22es%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode) (256 results)

   Other problems are related to Wikidata data quality.
2. The second problem is exact duplicates, e. g. [`wd:Q9648`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q9648) and [`wd:Q1249802`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1249802).
   The problem could be fixed in the same way as the next one.
3. The third problem is that ISO codes are applied both to a part and to a whole: compare [`wd:Q35`](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q35#P298) and [`wd:Q756617`](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q756617#P298); [`wd:Q55`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q55#P298) and [`wd:Q29999`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q29999#P298).
   One can get rid of such duplicates using `GROUP` and `SAMPLE`:

   ```
   SELECT ?code
     (SAMPLE(?label) AS ?label) 
     (MAX(?emoji) AS ?emoji)
     (SAMPLE(?flag) AS ?flag)  {
     # VALUES ?country {wd:Q414}
     ?country wdt:P298 ?code . FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q3024240 }
     ?country rdfs:label ?label . FILTER (lang(?label) = 'es') 
     OPTIONAL { ?country p:P1813 [ ps:P1813 ?emoji ; pq:P31 wd:Q28840786 ] }
     OPTIONAL { ?country wdt:P41 ?flag. }
   } GROUP BY ?code ORDER BY ?code
   ```

   [Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcode%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Flabel%29%20AS%20%3Flabel%29%20%0A%20%20%28MAX%28%3Femoji%29%20AS%20%3Femoji%29%0A%20%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Fflag%29%20AS%20%3Fflag%29%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%23%20VALUES%20%3Fcountry%20%7Bwd%3AQ414%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP298%20%3Fcode%20.%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%27es%27%29%20%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP1813%20%5B%20ps%3AP1813%20%3Femoji%20%3B%20pq%3AP31%20wd%3AQ28840786%20%5D%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP41%20%3Fflag.%20%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcode%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode) (250 results)

Comment: @LeandroTupone, I have edited my answer.